# Excel - Identifying when excluded codes are billed together

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Background:  I work in healthcare, and the proprietary software my company uses has not *quite* caught up with the new ICD-10 regulations.

I can export a list of all patients and all ICD-10 codes billed for each patient to Excel.  The patient names are in one column, the billing codes are in another column.

Certain ICD-10 codes cannot be billed together for the same patient, ex.: if `code A` and `code B` are billed for `Mary Smith`, the claim will be denied. I've created a list in a different spreadsheet with two columns of codes which is over 20k rows long.

I need to be able to identify if any of the patients in the first spreadsheet have excluded codes billed together.

I am currently using the following formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(COLUMN WITH PATIENT NAMES,FIRST CELL WITH PATIENT NAME,COLUMN WITH BILLING CODE,VLOOKUP(FIRST CELL WITH BILLING CODE,TABLE WITH EXCEPTIONS,2,FALSE))>0,"Code Error","")
```

This formula worked fine when I tested it with just a few excluded combinations, but it does not work with the full list of exceptions.

I'm thinking I might need an array formula of some sort, but I haven't really worked with those.

Any thoughts?

EDIT:  Here's a picture of what I'm working with - 
[Excel Data Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qp42C.jpg)

Comment: It is really hard to do this without pictures of the data.  I realize that you can not publicize patient info, but if you could mock up some data it would help use help you.

Comment: If the billing codes for each patient are lumped together in one column, why don't you just concatenate (with comma separator/or however it's separated in patient column) the two column excluded codes into one column and do a vlookup?

Comment: I am not guaranteeing this will work. I cannot properly test it.  Using your pseudo formula Try this: `=IF(SUMPRODUCT((COLUMN WITH PATIENT NAMES=FIRST CELL WITH PATIENT NAME)*(COLUMN WITH BILLING CODE=VLOOKUP(FIRST CELL WITH BILLING CODE,TABLE WITH EXCEPTIONS,2,FALSE))),"Code Error","")`

Comment: @ScottCraner I added a photo of the data, with dummy names, actual billing codes, and irrelevant columns hidden.  The formula you wrote above gives a "Value Not Available" error.

Comment: @findwindow I added a screenshot of what I'm working with.  I don't think concatenate will work, since the codes are in separate cells in one column, and there's always more than two codes per patient.

Comment: @LeslieM.B. this sounds nearly identical to something I have done (with procedure codes though).  I did it in in SQL though.  are you familiar with / do you have access to any databases?

Answer (score 0):

A PivotTable (people for Rows, ICD-10 codes for Columns, Count of people for Values) is, in theory, a way to create a matrix to which say Conditional Formatting rules could be applied to identify where clashes exist. However whether viable for this OP is not clear to me and I doubt will be clarified.